# R.java file disappears all of a sudden

Tags: android

While building my android project,at the initial stage R.java file which is automatically generated was present.But gradually when I went on building my application,it suddenly disappeared.What might be the reason for this?

Comment: check console what error do you get....

Comment: 11-08-16 10:20:55 - FormulaActivity] res\layout\ injectron.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]    This is the message displaying in the console.

Comment: remove space from the beginning of the injectron.xml...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can happen because of errors in resources. Usually the reason is malformed nine-patch image, but the actual problem is displayed in the Error Log view.

**EDIT**: According to your comment the problem is that injectron.xml file contains whitespace in its name. Just remove it and R.java will be regenerated again.

Comment: You need to find the error and remove it. Then you'll find R.java created instantly again.

Comment: @Mayu Mayooresan: Thanks for your useful comment. +1

Answer (score 3):

It might be deleted when Eclipse (suppose that you are using Eclipse IDE) rebuilds project and couldn't be regenerated automatically. I think that may be the reason. Change something in layout, string or id in res folder to see if R.java is regenerated again. If it does then you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

it have a error in xml file that you build.

The source code that is in your xml file is incomplete.

Have you try to check your xml?